# Como sacar borde que aparece como margin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para sacar los bordes que aparecen al costado de esta parte.
Adjunto imagen:
[image: Bordes como quedan]

Este es mi código, y me llama especial atención, que el `body` no tiene `margin`, tampoco tiene `padding`, entonces no sé que puede ser.

Mi HTML es este:

```
<section style="background-color: white; margin: 0 solid #fff; padding: 0;" id="galeria" class="container">
    <div class="text-center pt-5">
        <h2 style="color:white ; font-weight: 600;">Nuestros Clientes</h2>
        <p style="color:white;">Les presentamos a nuestros clientes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes1.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes2.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes3.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes4.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes5.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes6.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes7.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes8.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/Clientes9.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes10.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <a href="https://www.discorweb.com"><img src="images/Clientes11.jpg"
                    alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Y no tengo CSS, ya que uso Bootstrap en este caso. La versión es V3.1.0

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, intenta remover, en el section, la clase "container". Por lo que recuerdo, Bootstrap añade margen en esa clase. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Perfecto. Te hago una pregunta. Sabes como hacer para que Bootstrap no me tome las imágenes y no me las estire? A una en específica. Saludos! @Tupi

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre sería añadir la clase "img" a una imagen, pero no estoy para nada seguro de ello. Lo mejor seria crear una nueva pregunta el este foro preguntando específicamente ello. ^^

Comment: Gracias!! Saludos!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias probar a añadir un:

```
           margin-left: -40 px  o  margin-right: -40 px
```

Ajusta los px a tu gusto para que se vea bien

Creo que el problema se encuentra en Bootstrap que añade margen en esa clase.